# Expressjs acess names of uploaded files

Tags: node.js, express

I want to display names of all files.

Here is my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require("fs");

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer  = require('multer');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(multer({ dest: '/nodejs/diwanjidocs/tmp/'}).array('files'));


app.post('/file_upload', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.files);
    for(var i=0;i<req.files.length;i++){
        console.log(req.files.name);
    }
})


var server = app.listen(8081,'localhost',function () {

    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port

    console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)

})
```

For single file upload ***req.file.originalname*** returns filename but for multiple files how to get file names ?

Comment: Using only express you can't excess files that way. I recommend you to use multer library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
req.files.forEach(function (file) {
  console.log(file.originalname)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your form, but consinder the following form:

```
<form action="/uploadFiles" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" name="uploadedImages"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Then to handle the form you will include the:

```
 app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

And then you can manipulate the file array:

```
req.files.uploadedImages.forEach(function(photo, index, array) {
      console.log(photo.name);
});
```